# How to add the class to li when a section comes on the screen?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, scroll

I have to add the active class when a section is visible on the screen. I tried the below code but it's adding the class to all the `li` tags.

The below is the screenshot, The first `Row 1` is active. Now when `section` 2 comes onscreen then `Row 2` will active

[image]

Once reached show all the sections then it will display like this.

[image]

I have to slide red color like a progress bar.

```js
$(window).scroll(function() {
  $('section').each(function(i) {
    var bottom_of_object = $(this).offset().top + ($(this).outerHeight() * 0.3);
    var bottom_of_window = $(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height();
    if (bottom_of_window > bottom_of_object) {
      //$(this).addClass('animated');
      $(".rightwrap li").addClass("active");

    }
  });
});
```

```css
.mainWrapper {
  display: flex;
}

.leftWrap {
  width: 600px;
  margin: auto;
  border: 1px solid #222;
}

.rightwrap {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  right: 50px;
}

.h-500 {
  height: 650px
}

.dashlineWrap {
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
}

.vc_row {
  height: 500px;
}

.rightwrap ul li {
  position: relative;
  list-style: none;
  padding-bottom: 15px;
}

.rightwrap ul li::before {
  content: '';
  width: 2px;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #E5E5E5;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
}

.rightwrap ul li.active::before {
  background-color: red;
}

.rightwrap ul li a {
  padding-left: 15px;
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<div class="mainWrapper">
  <div class="leftWrap">
    <section class="dashlineWrap" id="section1">
      <div class="vc_row" id="tableofcontent-1">
        <h4>Row 1</h4>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo Lorem ipsum dolor sit
          amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing
          elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
          tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut
          labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna
          aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo</p>
      </div>
    </section>

    <section class="dashlineWrap" id="section2">

      <div class="vc_row h-500" id="tableofcontent-2">
        <h4>Row 2</h4>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute
          irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
      </div>
    </section>

    <section class="dashlineWrap" id="section3">

      <div class="vc_row h-500" id="tableofcontent-3">
        <h4>Row 3</h4>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute
          irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
      </div>
    </section>

  </div>

  <div class="rightwrap">
    <ul>
      <li class="active"><a href="">Row 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Row 2</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Row 3</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>

  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```js
let positions = [];
$('section').each(function(i, section) {
  positions.push($(section).offset().top);
});

$(window).scroll(function() {
  $(".rightwrap li").each(function(i, item) {
    item.classList.remove("active");
  });
  positions.forEach((secTop, idx) => {
    if(
      $(window).scrollTop() >= secTop && 
      ($(window).scrollTop() < positions[idx+1] || positions.length == (idx+1))
    )
      $(".rightwrap li")[idx].classList.add("active");
  });
});
```

```css
.mainWrapper {
  display: flex;
}

.leftWrap {
  width: 600px;
  margin: auto;
  border: 1px solid #222;
}

.rightwrap {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  right: 50px;
}

.h-500 {
  height: 650px
}

.dashlineWrap {
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
}

.vc_row {
  height: 500px;
}

.rightwrap ul li {
  position: relative;
  list-style: none;
  padding-bottom: 15px;
}

.rightwrap ul li::before {
  content: '';
  width: 2px;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #E5E5E5;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
}

.rightwrap ul li.active::before {
  background-color: red;
}

.rightwrap ul li a {
  padding-left: 15px;
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<div class="mainWrapper">
  <div class="leftWrap">
    <section class="dashlineWrap" id="section1">
      <div class="vc_row" id="tableofcontent-1">
        <h4>Row 1</h4>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo Lorem ipsum dolor sit
          amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing
          elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
          tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut
          labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna
          aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo</p>
      </div>
    </section>

    <section class="dashlineWrap" id="section2">

      <div class="vc_row h-500" id="tableofcontent-2">
        <h4>Row 2</h4>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute
          irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
      </div>
    </section>

    <section class="dashlineWrap" id="section3">

      <div class="vc_row h-500" id="tableofcontent-3">
        <h4>Row 3</h4>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute
          irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
      </div>
    </section>

  </div>

  <div class="rightwrap">
    <ul>
      <li class="active"><a href="">Row 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Row 2</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Row 3</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>

  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Give me sometime. let me try

Comment: It's not working as expected in snippet